# spark dealing with carbondata

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, carbon-data

Below is the code snippet I'm trying to use to create a carbondata table in S3. However, inspite of setting the aws credentials in hadoopconfiguration, it still complains about secret key and access key not being set. What is the issue here?

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonSession._
 import org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonSession._
 val carbon = SparkSession.builder().config(sc.getConf).getOrCreateCarbonSession("s3n://url")
carbon.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId","<accesskey>")
   carbon.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey","<secretaccesskey>")
carbon.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table(id string,name string,city string,age Int) STORED BY 'carbondata'")
```

Last command yields error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret
>   Access Key must be specified as the username or password
>   (respectively) of a s3n URL, or by setting the fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId
>   or fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively)

```
Spark Version : 2.2.1
Command used to start spark-shell:
$SPARK_PATH/bin/spark-shell --jars /localpath/jar/apache-carbondata-1.3.1-bin-spark2.2.1-hadoop2.7.2/apache-carbondata-1.3.1-bin-spark2.2.1-hadoop2.7.2.jar,/localpath/jar/spark-avro_2.11-4.0.0.jar --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.9.22,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2,org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.21,asm:asm:3.2,org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.7.1,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0
```

**UPDATE:**

Found that S3 support is only available in 1.4.0 RC1. So I built RC1 and tested the below code against the same. But still I seem to be running into issues. Any help appreciated.
Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonSession._
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Constants.{ACCESS_KEY, ENDPOINT, SECRET_KEY}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.carbondata.core.constants.CarbonCommonConstants
object sample4 {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val (accessKey, secretKey, endpoint) = getKeyOnPrefix("s3n://")
//val rootPath = new File(this.getClass.getResource("/").getPath
//                            + "../../../..").getCanonicalPath
val path = "/localpath/sample/data1.csv"
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("S3UsingSDKExample")
      .config("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
      .config(accessKey, "<accesskey>")
      .config(secretKey, "<secretkey>")
      //.config(endpoint, "s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
      .getOrCreateCarbonSession()
      spark.sql("Drop table if exists carbon_table")

    spark.sql(
      s"""
         | CREATE TABLE if not exists carbon_table(
         | shortField SHORT,
         | intField INT,
         | bigintField LONG,
         | doubleField DOUBLE,
         | stringField STRING,
         | timestampField TIMESTAMP,
         | decimalField DECIMAL(18,2),
         | dateField DATE,
         | charField CHAR(5),
         | floatField FLOAT
         | )
         | STORED BY 'carbondata'
         | LOCATION 's3n://bucketName/table/carbon_table'
         | TBLPROPERTIES('SORT_COLUMNS'='', 'DICTIONARY_INCLUDE'='dateField, charField')
       """.stripMargin)

}


def getKeyOnPrefix(path: String): (String, String, String) = {
    val endPoint = "spark.hadoop." + ENDPOINT
    if (path.startsWith(CarbonCommonConstants.S3A_PREFIX)) {
      ("spark.hadoop." + ACCESS_KEY, "spark.hadoop." + SECRET_KEY, endPoint)
    } else if (path.startsWith(CarbonCommonConstants.S3N_PREFIX)) {
      ("spark.hadoop." + CarbonCommonConstants.S3N_ACCESS_KEY,
        "spark.hadoop." + CarbonCommonConstants.S3N_SECRET_KEY, endPoint)
    } else if (path.startsWith(CarbonCommonConstants.S3_PREFIX)) {
      ("spark.hadoop." + CarbonCommonConstants.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
        "spark.hadoop." + CarbonCommonConstants.S3_SECRET_KEY, endPoint)
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Incorrect Store Path")
    }
  }
  def getSparkMaster(args: Array[String]): String = {
    if (args.length == 6) args(5)
    else if (args(3).contains("spark:") || args(3).contains("mesos:")) args(3)
    else "local"
  }
}
```

Error:

> ```
> 18/05/17 12:23:22 ERROR SegmentStatusManager: main Failed to read metadata of load
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception: org.jets3t.service.ServiceException: Request Error: Empty key
> ```

I also tried against the sample code in (tried s3,s3n,s3a protocols as well):

```
https://github.com/apache/carbondata/blob/master/examples/spark2/src/main/scala/org/apache/carbondata/examples/S3Example.scala
```

Ran as:

> S3Example.main(Array("accesskey","secretKey","s3://bucketName/path/carbon_table","https://bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com","local"))

Error stacktrace:

> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception:
>   org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Request Error: Empty key   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.get(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.retrieveINode(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:221)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.retrieveINode(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem.getFileStatus(S3FileSystem.java:340)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)     at
>   org.apache.carbondata.core.datastore.filesystem.AbstractDFSCarbonFile.isFileExist(AbstractDFSCarbonFile.java:426)
>     at
>   org.apache.carbondata.core.datastore.impl.FileFactory.isFileExist(FileFactory.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.carbondata.core.statusmanager.SegmentStatusManager.readTableStatusFile(SegmentStatusManager.java:246)
>     at
>   org.apache.carbondata.core.statusmanager.SegmentStatusManager.readLoadMetadata(SegmentStatusManager.java:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.carbondata.core.cache.dictionary.ManageDictionaryAndBTree.clearBTreeAndDictionaryLRUCache(ManageDictionaryAndBTree.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.CarbonFileMetastore.dropTable(CarbonFileMetastore.scala:460)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.table.CarbonCreateTableCommand.processMetadata(CarbonCreateTableCommand.scala:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.MetadataCommand.run(package.scala:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:67)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:183)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonSession$$anonfun$sql$1.apply(CarbonSession.scala:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonSession$$anonfun$sql$1.apply(CarbonSession.scala:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonSession.withProfiler(CarbonSession.scala:144)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonSession.sql(CarbonSession.scala:94)   at
>   $line19.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$S3Example$.main(:68)   at $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:31)
>     at $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:36)   at
>   $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:38)    at
>   $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:40)    at
>   $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:42)    at
>   $line26.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:44)    at
>   $line26.$read$$iw$$iw.(:46)    at
>   $line26.$read$$iw.(:48)    at
>   $line26.$read.(:50)    at
>   $line26.$read$.(:54)   at
>   $line26.$read$.()    at
>   $line26.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(:7)     at
>   $line26.$eval$.$print(:6)    at $line26.$eval.$print()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)  at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)   at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)    at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:415)   at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:923)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)   at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:74)     at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:54)   at
>   org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused
>   by: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Request Error: Empty key
>     at org.jets3t.service.S3Service.getObject(S3Service.java:1470)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.get(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:163)

Is any of the arguments that I'm passing wrong.
I'm able to access the s3 path using aws cli:

> aws s3 ls s3://bucketName/path

exists in S3.

Answer (score 3):

You can try it using this example https://github.com/apache/carbondata/blob/master/examples/spark2/src/main/scala/org/apache/carbondata/examples/S3Example.scala

You have to provide aws credentials properties to spark first after that you will be creating carbonSession.

If you have already created sparkContext without aws properties being provided. Then it do not pick up those properties even after you give it to carbonContext.

Comment: Looks like in the latest release 1.3.1, S3 support is not available. In the sample code above it references - CarbonCommonConstants.S3_PREFIX . However in the source code as part of 1.3.1: carbondata-parent-1.3.1/core/src/main/java/org/apache/carbondata/core/constants/CarbonCommonConstants.java, I see that constant isnt even defined.

Comment: Yes, its support is provided in 1.4.0-RC1 release

Comment: Ok Thanks for clarification! Let me try the RC1 and see if it works for me!

Comment: I tried against 1.4.0 RC1. Could you check the code I pasted above and let me know what I'm doing wrong. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

hi vikas looking at your exception empty key simply means that your acesss key and secret key is not binded in carbon session because when we give the s3 implementation we write the logic that if any of key is not provide by user then it then their value should be taken as empty

so to make things easy 
first build the carbon data jar using this command

mvn -Pspark-2.1 clean package
then execute spark submit with this command

./spark-submit --jars file:///home/anubhav/Downloads/softwares/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/carbonlib/apache-carbondata-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT-bin-spark2.2.1-hadoop2.7.2.jar --class org.apache.carbondata.examples.S3Example /home/anubhav/Documents/carbondata/carbondata/carbondata/examples/spark2/target/carbondata-examples-spark2-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar    local

replace my jar path with yours and see it should work,its working for me